# Catching exception inside a decorator

Tags: python, exception, decorator, python-decorators

This questions may not be correct theoretically but would like to know if there is any workaround.

Let's consider the following example:

```
def my_function():
    try:
        print("before the exception occurs")
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('exception found')

    print("after the exception occurs")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_function()
```

if you print to stdout, the output should be as follows:

```
before the exception occurs
exception found
after the exception occurs
```

However, if you use a decorator to catch the exception as below:

```
from functools import wraps


def decorator(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        print('exception found')

  return wrapper


@decorator
def my_exception_function():
  print("before the exception occurs")

  raise ValueError

  print("after the exception occurs")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  my_exception_function()
```

the rest of the function after the exception occurs will not be executed as below:

```
before the exception occurs
exception found
```

Therefore, I would like to know if there any workaround that I can use to get the first example output but using a decorator to catch the exception.

Comment: You want to be able to return to a later point inside the wrapped function after catching the error from outside it? That's not going to work, the wrapped function invocation has finished.

Comment: There is no way to continue code execution of code block with exception after exception was raised. Even if you catch it.

Comment: Imagine that you have lines like `a = 1 / 0 \n print(a)`. Even if you catch ZeroDivisionError, how can you print a after it? What value will it have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to inline the `my_exception_func` inside the decorator.

```
from functools import wraps


def decorator(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    try:
        print("before the exception occurs")
        raise ValueError
        print("after the exception occurs")
    except ValueError:
        print('exception found')

  return wrapper
```

So now the control flow should be more clear:

- Print 'before the exception'
- Exception raised
- Go to the `except block`
- return

Due to the exception, the 'after exception' print is never reached.

Using  a try-except block to catch the exception, but then executing the code after the point of exception doesn't really work. You'll need to isolate **exactly** where the exception might happen and wrap only that part in the try-except block.